# What is the Best way to handle groups and sub-groups filter in Mobile App

Tags: mobile, ux-field, grouped-list

I am a developer, NOT a designer.

I am working on a Web App in which Assets are divided into Companies, Sites and Categories

So the Hierarchy is something like this:

```
Company 1
   Site 1
      Category 1
          Asset A
          Asset B
          Asset C
      Category 2
          Asset 1
          Asset 2
          Asset 3
   Site 2
      Category A
          Asset I
          Asset II
      Category B
          Asset III

Company 2
  ............ So on
```

Now in Web Apps I use either `cascading dropdowns`:

[image]

or a `Tree Control` in some places

[image]

So now that I want to start working on the Mobile App for this (Tablet + SmartPhone), what is the best practice for displaying this type of data in Mobile Apps? So that User can filter by `Sites/Categories` and view the Assets.

Comment: Do you need to be able to view the assets for multiple categories simultaneously? Or just one category at a time?

Comment: @GrahamHerrli The user can select either one category or All of them ( so there will be an option for all).

Answer (score 1):

You can just implement a straight forward approach similar below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: so when the user clicks on the Company button it shows list of companies, the user selects a company and the list is refreshed?

Comment: yes. for the actions events and animation you can run a pre built test that would fit your need.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 different examples

1. Omni Outliner (3 hierarchies in one page)
   [image: Omni Outliner]
2. Evernote (2 hierarchies, the final hierarchy is in the next page after you click)
   [image]
3. Explorer for GitHub (Use the sidebar menu to filter)
   [image]